# Is there a way to stop html from making line breaks when a tag is in another tag?

Tags: javascript, html

So I would like to make a calculator with some formatting to make it look nice. It keeps making a new line for my p tag and I don't want it to, is there any fix for this?

```js
var n1 = document.getElementById("n1");
var n2 = document.getElementById("n2");
var display = document.getElementById("disp");

function addAndDisplay() {
  display.innerHTML = (Number(n1.value)+Number(n2.value)).toString();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Addition</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Addition</h1>
    <h3>Value one:</h3>
    <input type="number" id="n1">
    <h3>Value two:</h3>
    <input type="number" id="n2">
    <br>
    <button onclick="addAndDisplay()">Add</button>
    <h3>The output: <p id="disp">You have not calculated anything yet</p>.</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Thanks @Pipe and @Pointy I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: Side note, you have no `disp` variable declared in `disp.innerHTML`. Also `<p>` elements are block level, so maybe try changing its display to inline. `#disp {
display:inline;
}`

Comment: Why are you putting the content in a paragraph tag if you don't want it ti look like a paragraph?

Comment: @j08691 Sorry I messed up, should be fixed.

Comment: Then you can try a `<span>` element instead of a `<p>` element

Comment: @Pointy Is there some text tag I don't know about?

Comment: Well if you don't want a new line, then don't use the p tag, see w3schools for html tag references

Comment: uhh `<span>` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per default, a [paragraph](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) is a [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements). This means that it starts on a new line and takes up the full width. Maybe you should consider using something else.

For this kind of usecase, you would want to use `<span></span>`. [Span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) is using `display: inline` which allows multiple inline-elements to appear next to each other.

It might be useful to read [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) about the CSS `display` property - it will help you understand the suggested solution much better.

Comment: This works to. I accept all answers!

Answer (score 1):

you shuld use span instead of p. p is paragraph element and span can be used to group elements for styling purposes

Comment: I will accept this answer when I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var n1 = document.getElementById("n1");
var n2 = document.getElementById("n2");
var display = document.getElementById("disp");

function addAndDisplay() {
  display.innerHTML = (Number(n1.value)+Number(n2.value)).toString();
}
```

```css
p{
display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Addition</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Addition</h1>
    <h3>Value one:</h3>
    <input type="number" id="n1">
    <h3>Value two:</h3>
    <input type="number" id="n2">
    <br>
    <button onclick="addAndDisplay()">Add</button>
    <h3>The output: <p id="disp">You have not calculated anything yet</p>.</h3>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will start leaving comments on every answer. Pipe and Pointy and Kowalkox and nah0131 all said the <span> element. Still, I appreciate your help!